# PHP page calling a PHP file - Confused about Cache

Tags: php, cache-control

I have a PHP page, let's say it's my landing page, `landing.php`.

When a user hits this php some code is run and it calls `getNames.php` through AJAX.

I'm pushing out a massive update to the getNames.php file and I want users to get access to the fresh file instead of the old cached file so I'm going to specify some cache headers.

If both `landing.php` and `getNames.php` are cached, do I need to specify the cache headers on both or just the `getNames.php` file?

As far as I am aware, AJAX caches it's requests which is why I am thinking I may need to do it on both files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In the case as you explained the `AJAX call` being done 
  from `landing.php` and the response of ajax came from `getNames.php`.So there
  is no meaning to put cache header in `getNames.php` because its
  always give the data as your per need in `AJAX response`.
- So that you only need to put cache header in `landing.php`.When the
  user hit `landing.php` the cache will be clear and the new data will be 
  loaded from the `AJAX response`.
- It will useful to put cache header in case when you 
  don't make `AJAX call` and you do call the page  `getNames.php`